How to limit the number of connections for a shape in draw.io / app.diagrams.net xml code?
I would like to allow only a single connection to an element in draw.io. How to do so? I created a single connection point (see xml code below) and do not want to allow extra connections to the shape:

However, additional floating connections are still allowed:

The property snapToPoint=1 enables snapping. However, snapping only works close to the connection point. It is still possible to create conenctions that do not snap to the single, predefined connection point.
I could not find a property to restrict the allowed connections to this single connection point. Did I miss something?
<mxGraphModel>
    <root>
        <mxCell id="0"/>
        <mxCell id="1" parent="0"/>

        <object id="source" label="source">
            <mxCell id="source_cell" style="points=[[1,0.5]];snapToPoint=1;shape=ellipse;fillColor=green;opacity=50;"
                    vertex="1"
                    parent="1">
                <mxGeometry as="geometry" width="100" height="40"/>
            </mxCell>
        </object>

        <mxCell
                id="source_edge"
                source="source"
                target=""
                edge="1"
                style="endArrow=classic;"
                parent="1"
        >
            <mxGeometry as="geometry" relative="1">
                <mxPoint x="100" y="20" as="sourcePoint"/>
                <mxPoint x="150" y="20" as="targetPoint"/>
            </mxGeometry>
        </mxCell>

    </root>
</mxGraphModel>

Related:
How to allow incoming connections only from the left side of a shape in draw.io /app.diagrams.net?
https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues/4790

If you downvote, please let me know why.
